# How to set two icons on a single activity on android

Tags: android

[image: Activity Screen shot]

On my MainActivity i want to place two icons as dipicted on the image above.(The Addidas logos).

Does anyone know how i can go about archiving this on android?

Comment: create your own view with 2 imageviews?

Comment: What have you tried? This could be as simple as having a separate layout at the top of your activity (if you're not using the action bar). If you intend to use the action bar, you may want to look into setting a custom view that takes up the whole width. That does mean you won't be able to add any action items. In any case, I'd recommend to read through the [action bar guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), because the suggested styling is quite non-Android.

Comment: Currently my action bar is full, and i don't want to flood it with options.

Comment: so dont use an actionbar in your app then. the only way you can accomplish what you want is by creating your own view and not using the actionbar

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `LinearLayout` for this header.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        //Put elements here
         <ImageView/>
         <TextView/>
         <ImageView/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

You can have a look about common layouts [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts).